# Bind Window item to usercontrol underlying control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Been a long time visitor of this site but this will be the first post for me. Hoping I can get a little help here. Been looking around and so far no luck or I am misreading what I am looking at. Here is the situation I am trying to overcome.

I am trying to Bind a (Main Window) TextBlock text to a DependencyProperty of a custom control that is within a User Control on my main window.

Breaks down like this. 
Class Library Project: BindTest
Custom Control:

```
 namespace BindTest.Controls
{  
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;

    public class Picker : Control
    {
        static Picker()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Picker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Picker)));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Hue Property
        /// </summary>
        public double Hue
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(HueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HueProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty HueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Hue", typeof(double), typeof(Picker),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0,
            new PropertyChangedCallback(UpdateColorHSB),
            new CoerceValueCallback(HueCoerce)));

        public static object HueCoerce(DependencyObject d, object Hue)
        {
            double v = (double)Hue;
            if (v < 0) return 0.0;
            if (v > 1) return 1.0;
            return v;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Shared property changed callback to update the Color property
        /// </summary>
        public static void UpdateColorHSB(object o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Picker c = (Picker)o;
           // Do work
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have a User Control that will use this Custom Control (PickerPlugin.xaml) Nothing in the code behind. Nothing special here.

```
 <UserControl               
                 x:Class="BindTest.PickerPlugin"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindTest"
                 xmlns:cntrls="clr-namespace:BindTest.Controls"
                 FontSize="7.75pt" Foreground="#DDD" FontFamily="Verdana"
                 Width="200" Height="200">

        <Grid>
            <StackPanel Margin="1">
                <TextBlock Margin="0,2,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Model</TextBlock>
                <cntrls:Picker x:Name="C" />
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=C, Path=Hue}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>        
    </UserControl>
```

That is it for the control. I want to use this control now on my mainwindow but I want to be able to access the Hue property from this element (cntrls:Picker x:Name="C" ) just like I have it here in the control.

All I have in my main window is the following:

```
<Grid>
    <test:PickerPlugin x:Name="Picker" Grid.Column="0"  />        
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Picker, Path=Hue}" />        
</Grid>
```

I cannot figure out how to access that Hue property from that User Control. I am hoping there is some way to access that Hue property from the element in the user control? Hope this makes sense and someone can help!

Thanks!

Comment: You can read here about it - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224230/Exploring-the-use-of-Dependency-Properties-in-User

Comment: Thank you I have already seen that one and don't see how it does what I am looking for? These sample only bind on one level of the main user control. I am looking to go another level down to control within control.

Comment: I assume you checked your output for binding errors?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i'm sure that I'm only copying some from that article, but maybe for you will be easier to understand this stuff on other sample.

I have create new Solution WpfTest and two projects: WpfTest and WpfControlLibrary1.

MainWindow.xaml of WpfTest:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
    xmlns:WpfControlLibrary1="clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary1;assembly=WpfControlLibrary1" x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding Some, ElementName=UserControl1}" Margin="239,0,0,188" />
    <WpfControlLibrary1:UserControl1 Name="UserControl1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="60,54,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Margin="0,224,164,0" />
</Grid>
```

WpfControlLibrary1.UserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfControlLibrary1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary1"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <local:SomeControl Width="100" Height="100" Content="{Binding Some, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
</Grid>
```

As you can see, I have create also SomeControl:

```
public class SomeControl : ContentControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Some", typeof (int),
        typeof (SomeControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(10) {Inherits = true});

    public int Some
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(SomeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SomeProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

We have SomeProperty here. It's type is int and it have wrapper, metadata that marked as inheritable.
If we want to use it from MainWindow we must create something on UserControl level, let see what we have:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeProperty = SomeControl.SomeProperty.AddOwner(
        typeof (UserControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata() {Inherits = true});

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int Some
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(SomeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SomeProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I have create property SomProperty in UserControl1 too and wrapper, but instead of Register new Dependency property I have AddOwner to property of SomeControl.

Little test of our sample. We have click event on button in MainWindow:

```
    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1.Some++;
    }
```

As result we can see, that value in Label and on SomeControl was changed after click.

Comment: That worked great! I see what I missed there. Really appreciate it!